AWS Glue how to debug an Invalid Connection String?
I've got a documentDB setup in a VPC, 2 private subnets (call them A and B).
I setup the Glue connection by selecting the appropriate VPC, subnet A, and a security group that has subnet access.
I added the documentDB url and manually added the username/password. Database name is correct and SSL is enabled.
In the end I get this connection string (edited slightly)
mongodb://username:mypassword@my-documentdb-cluster-1234567890.us-west-2.docdb-elastic.amazonaws.com:27017/Chimera/?ssl=true'
This looks fine, but I get
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o106.getDynamicFrame. Invalid connection string
When I try to start a data session or run the job.
I have verified in my code and this connection string looks identical to the one used in the app for connecting to DocumentDB.

Have you encoded the password? If you have a password like this '?test123/' it should be converted to -> '%3Ftest123%2F'.

If you are using Glue connection feature, the connectionstring for DocumentDB/MongoDB should be defined in below format:
mongodb://mongoHost:mongoPort/mongoDBname

And username/password should be passed via AWS secret manager or in those input parameters directly(as shown in the screenshot).

Another point: You can directly test the connection string using Test connection via AWS Glue Connection.
Please check the documentation for creating MongoDB connection for detailed overview.
